# Populating my AVLTree is taking a very long time

Tags: java, data-structures, avl-tree

At the moment, it takes roughly 28 seconds to populate my AVLTree with 11000 objects which is way too slow and when I attempt to populate the Tree with 250000 objects, the program never completes its run.

Currently I'm not really sure what is causing it to run so slowly. Could it be that I am using too much recursion? And if so how could I use less?

```
public class AVLTree<K, V> implements AVLTreeI<K, V> {

    class Node<K, V> {

        K key;
        V value;
        Node<K, V> leftChild;
        Node<K, V> rightChild;
        Node<K, V> parent;

        public Node(K key, V value) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            leftChild = rightChild = parent = null;
        }
    }

    private Node<K, V> root;
    private int currentSize;

    public AVLTree() {
        root = null;
        currentSize = 0;
    }

    public void add(K key, V value) {
        Node<K, V> node = new Node<K, V>(key, value);

        if (root == null) {
            root = node;
            currentSize++;
            return;
        }

        add(root, node);
    }

    private void add(Node<K, V> parent, Node<K, V> newNode) {
        if (((Comparable<K>) newNode.key).compareTo(parent.key) > 0) {
            if (parent.rightChild == null) {
                parent.rightChild = newNode;
                newNode.parent = parent;
                currentSize++;
            } else {
                add(parent.rightChild, newNode);
            }
        } else {
            if (parent.leftChild == null) {
                parent.leftChild = newNode;
                newNode.parent = parent;
                currentSize++;
            } else {
                add(parent.leftChild, newNode);
            }
        }

        checkBalance(newNode);
    }

    public int height() {
        if (root == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        return height(root) - 1;
    }

    private int height(Node<K, V> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int leftHeight = height(node.leftChild) + 1;
        int rightHeight = height(node.rightChild) + 1;

        if (leftHeight > rightHeight) {
            return leftHeight;
        }

        return rightHeight;
    }

    public void checkBalance(Node<K, V> node) {
        if ((height(node.leftChild) - height(node.rightChild) > 1)
                || (height(node.leftChild) - height(node.rightChild) < -1)) {
            rotate(node);
        }

        if (node.parent == null) {
            return;
        }

        checkBalance(node.parent);
    }

    public void rotate(Node<K, V> node) {
        if (height(node.leftChild) - height(node.rightChild) > 1) {
            if (height(node.leftChild.leftChild)
                    > height(node.leftChild.rightChild)) {
                node = rightRotate(node);
            } else {
                node = leftRightRotate(node);
            }
        } else {
            if (height(node.rightChild.rightChild)
                    > height(node.rightChild.leftChild)) {
                node = leftRotate(node);
            } else {
                node = rightLeftRotate(node);
            }
        }

        if (node.parent == null) {
            root = node;
        }
    }

    public Node<K, V> leftRotate(Node<K, V> node) {
        Node<K, V> tmp = node.rightChild;
        Node<K, V> rightLeftChild = null;

        if (tmp.leftChild != null) {
            rightLeftChild = node.rightChild.leftChild;
        }

        node.rightChild = tmp.leftChild;
        tmp.leftChild = node;

        if (rightLeftChild != null) {
            tmp.leftChild.rightChild = rightLeftChild;
            tmp.leftChild.rightChild.parent = tmp.leftChild;
        }

        tmp.parent = node.parent;
        tmp.leftChild.parent = tmp;

        if (tmp.parent != null) {
            if (tmp.parent.leftChild == node) {
                tmp.parent.leftChild = tmp;
            }

            if (tmp.parent.rightChild == node) {
                tmp.parent.rightChild = tmp;
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    public Node<K, V> rightRotate(Node<K, V> node) {
        Node<K, V> tmp = node.leftChild;
        Node<K, V> leftRightChild = null;

        if (tmp.rightChild != null) {
            leftRightChild = node.leftChild.rightChild;
        }

        node.leftChild = tmp.rightChild;
        tmp.rightChild = node;

        if (leftRightChild != null) {
            tmp.rightChild.leftChild = leftRightChild;
            tmp.rightChild.leftChild.parent = tmp.rightChild;
        }

        tmp.parent = node.parent;
        tmp.rightChild.parent = tmp;

        if (tmp.parent != null) {
            if (tmp.parent.leftChild == node) {
                tmp.parent.leftChild = tmp;
            }

            if (tmp.parent.rightChild == node) {
                tmp.parent.rightChild = tmp;
            }
        }

        return tmp;
    }

    public Node<K, V> rightLeftRotate(Node<K, V> node) {
        node.rightChild = rightRotate(node.rightChild);
        return leftRotate(node);
    }

    public Node<K, V> leftRightRotate(Node<K, V> node) {
        node.leftChild = leftRotate(node.leftChild);
        return rightRotate(node);
    }
}
```

Comment: The most time-consuming operation in the algorithm is probably the key comparison; however, you can "derecursify" a few things, starting with the `height` function.

Comment: @MauricePerry How could I go about changing my height function?

Comment: you can keep the height of the tree in the `Node` object.